# Check users are allowed to register or not in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I created a plugin for WordPress. In this plugin, users can register in our WordPress, but I have a problem.

I want to check users are allowed to register or not. There is an option in WordPress for membership; with this option, we can let users register on our website or not.

Now I want to know in my plugin admin checked this option or not. I searched on google, but I couldn't find any hooks or functions for this part.

You can see membership in `settings -> general` ,

[image]

---

***Solved***

---

For solving this problem there is a simple way is just check options in database with `get_option('users_can_register')` we can check if it is 1 then users can register else they can not.

```
if (get_option('users_can_register') == 1) {

    // do something

}else{

    // do else

}
```